# While looping through Azure VMs in powershell I want to get only VMs which have specific tag available in those

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

```
     Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.ResourceGroupName -eq "somename" -and $_.Tags.Keys -like "tagName*"} | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output($_.Name);
 }
```

The problem here is that is VM does not have any tag available then it throws the error.
***You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.***
If there is only one tag then in where clause **TAG** works not **Tags**.
There is a way around to check count first and then apply Tag or Tags accordingly but whole point of getting only selective VMs is to enhance the performance of my code not degrade it by using count and if else every time.

Comment: Yes, you can just get the count first or the list of TagNames. Yet, have you tried using -contains, or -match first.

Comment: Could you please try to use `$_.Tags.Keys -contains ""`?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if the Tag keys [contain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/removing-objects-from-the-pipeline--where-object-?view=powershell-7.1#performing-simple-tests-with-where-object) the `tagName` you're looking for.

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> | Where-Object { $_.Tags.Keys -contains "tagName" }
```

This should work irrespective of whether a VM resource has none/single/multiple tags.

[image: Get Tags]

Comment: It will work only if we have multiple tags if in case we have single tag or no tag in that case it will not work. because in that case $_.Tag.keys work.

Comment: @AmarjitSinghChaudhary No, that is not the case. I see the correct results on my end as posted in the screenshot above. Please try and include a screenshot if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @AmarjitSinghChaudhary Any luck here?